# Sorting a "Find" using methods rather than fields in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a ticket model which has a method inside called `closes_in` that calculates the time left from the DB field `start_date:date` to now.  Currently my find query is:

```
    @tickets = Ticket.find(:all, 
                       :origin => @user.coords, 
                       :order => 'distance',
```

I can't just put in closes_in as I get an error.  How do I make it so I can use `closes_in` to sort the query if it's a method and not an actual field in the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL:

```
@tickets = Ticket.all(:order => "DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), start_date)")
```

If you are using PostgreSQL:

```
@tickets = Ticket.all(:order => "AGE(start_date)")
```

This way you are using DB for sorting. Sorting using ruby should be restricted to a small data-set that is guaranteed to remain small.

Comment: Thanks!  So in this case, I'll probably go with your solution though it will help to know the Ruby alternative that jpemberthy put above for other complicated methods that might not be easy to calculate in the DB.

Comment: I use ruby sorting to smaller datasets(0-1000). When you need to perform pagination, grouping, sorting etc. its always better use built-in DB functionality before resorting to ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003120) method:

```
@tickets = Ticket.find(:all, :conditions => "foo").sort_by { |t| t.closes_in }
```

Comment: How do you control in this example sorting ascending or descending?

Comment: By default the `sort_by` method will return the collection ordered `ASC`, for `DESC` order you have to negate the `sort_by` elements, e.g: `Ticket.find(:all, :conditions => "foo").sort_by { |t| -t.closes_in }` (note the minus '-') returns the `@tickets` ordered `DESC`.